# Yum freezes on Running Transaction Check

Tags: centos, centos5, yum, kernel

Strace: http://pastebin.com/r8D39yLg Kernel:

2.6.18-274.12.1.el5.centos.plus #1 SMP Tue Nov 29 18:16:47 EST 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64

GNU/Linux System: CentOS 5.7 64-bit

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this problem is usually due to a stale nfs mount, or some other blocking IO.

kill the yum process with a "kill -9", resolve the filesystem issue, and try the yum command again.

Comment: I do not use any NFS mount points.

Comment: My current /etc/fstab: http://pastebin.com/dn2Z2d0Z

Comment: can you stat both the `stat /home` and `stat /var/lib/mysql` dirs?

Comment: Sure: http://pastebin.com/rnP92uaN

Comment: Reboot fixed this problem ;)

Comment: [pedantry alert] That is most definitely a work-around to the problem. ;-)

Comment: I've updated the kernel and problem seems to be back- 2.6.18-274.18.1.el5.centos.plus

Comment: It started to work again... ;)